# How to deploy Django on share host?

Tags: python, django, share, host

I upload the project to a shared hosting account, and the .htaccess:

```
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /yuanzhe/mysite/mysite/mysite2.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

but found 404 when I visit http://youdishou.com/hello

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Second argument to `RewriteRule` should be an URL:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite2.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Anyway, visit http://youdishou.com/mysite2.fcgi

Looks like your hosting provider does not support fcgi at all. So it's better to contact hosting support to know if there is a way to start Django there. Many providers do not support Django at all.